# Suppose that a fair 6-sides die is rolled 4 times

Tags: probability

Suppose that a fair 6-sided die is rolled 4 times. Letting N be the minimum number of spots observed on the 4 upward faces obtained, and X be the maximum number of spots obtained, give the value of P(N = 2, X = 5).

A hint that is given is that it is very easy to get the probabilities of events such as 3 < N < X < 5, 2 < N < X < 5, 2 < N < X < 4, and maybe these probabilities can be used?

I am very lost on how to go about even starting this problem. I did find a link that explains probabilities dealing with minimums and maximums of dice rolls:
https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/correlation-illustrated-minimum-and-maximum-of-die-rolls/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are $6^4$ possible outcomes so all we have to do is count how many of those satisfy $N=2$ and $X=5$.

Notice that there are $4^4$ outcomes that do not contain $1$ or $6$.

From these let us substract the $3^4$ outcomes that do not contain $2$ and the $3^4$ that do not contain $5$.

Then add back the $2^4$ that dont contain either

Final answer:

$\frac{4^4-3^4 - 3^4 + 2^4}{6^4}$